# ExtJS move component to another layout

Tags: extjs

I have some GridPanel. Can I write a plugin which will create Panel with BorderLayout and push my grid to this Panel with region === 'center' and FormPanel with region === 'west', for example? In another words, I want to get my component and completely move it to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are asking to move a component after it has been rendered.

I would recommend setting up your BorderLayout with some more basic containers (or panels if you wish) for each region.  Then add your grid and form panels to *those* containers rather than directly to the BorderLayout Panel.

At that point, you can simply get whichever component you want and .add() or .insert() it to some other container.  In extjs 3.2.1, at least, add() and insert() both take care of the entire move.  Don't remove() them.